# Защита от двойной отправки формы на сервере

Tags: php, форма

При отправке данных формы во избежании двойной отправки я посредством скрипта делаю кнопку submit неактивной. Попалась книжка, где говорится о том, что в целях безопасности на сервере все равно должна быть проверка на двойную оправку. Я всегда использовал вообще для проверки на санкционированную отправку скрытое поле формы с некоторым значением сессионной переменной. Но при двойной отправке такая проверка ничего не даст - эти значения дважды совпадут.  Интересно, как такую проверку реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает помещать значение этой сессионной переменной в базу после первой отправки и помечать ее как использованную? Это вполне стандартный прием, даже на серьезных сайтах. Например, контент-провайдеры таким образом защищают ссылки на т.н. "одноразовое скачивание" от тех, кто решит поделиться ссылкой с друзьями, после того, как скачал сам. Причем значения этих сессионных переменных генерируются на лету (после, скажем, подтверждения оплаты контента), выдаются в ссылку, как дополнительный `GET` параметр, затем ждут своего часа стать помеченными, как использованными, после того, как заплативший перейдет по ней. Иногда дается ограничение по времени - значение может стать недействительным, если с момента генерации и до запроса прошло, скажем, больше 5 минут. Ссылка с таким уникальным хешем в качестве сессионной переменной становится недействительной после будучи использованной единожды.

Comment: Об этом я и подумал, но ведь таблица будет заполняться записями до бесконечности. Или ее нужно как-то очищать?

Comment: Сделайте с точностью наоборот) есть запись в таблице с переменной - валидно, запись использовалась - удалите ее, можно очищать просроченые записи допустим раз в час\день..... решит много проблем, в т.ч. и с разрастанием таблицы

Comment: По простому:
 
    1)показали пользователю форму. в форме скрытое поле с переменной которую только что создали и записали в базу(айди,переменная,время,...)
    2)Забываем о том что у нас был пользователь :)
    3)Пользователь отправил вам данные.
    4)Очистили базу от старых переменных.(поле время нам в помосч).
    5)Проверили есть ли переменная полученая от пользователя в базе.
     5а)да  > удаляем переменную и пишем в базу данные.
     5б)нет > сообщаем пользователю или игнорируем отправку.

Comment: Все понятненько, кроме 

4)Очистили базу от старых переменных.(поле время нам в помосч).

Если это про сессионную переменную, то ее удалять не нужно, как раз с ней и будет происходить проверка.

Comment: Очистили из базы просроченые переменные, вы же не будете ждать день\неделю\месяц\год(нужное подчеркнуть) данных от пользователя?
т.е. сессионный ключ(ключ для отправки формы) выдается пользователю на время! чтоб незабивать таблицу.

    delete from form_keys where `время`=`совсем просрочено`

Comment: Такой вариант - при отправке формы ключ из формы сверяется с БД - существует ли? Если не существует, то ключ фиксируется в таблице и форма обрабатывается, если существует - значит это была повторная отправка, ничего не делать. Далее, ваш пункт 5.

Зачем записывать ключ заранее?? Может пользователь вообще не будет отправлять форму. Лишний мусор в БД.